# How can deploy a DLL using RegAsm for COM Interop?

Tags: vba, vb.net

I have a vb.net dll [DTP_Image.dll] at local : if i build by VS 2010, it load ok:
[image]

But i deploy dll on a other PCs by command:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /codebase "C:\deploydll\DTP_Image.dll"
```

[image]

I can't found my dll in [Tool -> Reference] of Excel VBA.

How can deploy a DLL using RegAsm for COM Interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the types by calling regasm like this

`regasm.exe {your.dll} /register /codebase /tlb`