# How to substitue a VBA Code Compiled to a dll file in my excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I compiled my VBA code into a dll file. Now I want to use/call this file in my workbook instead of the Original VBA code. I have no ideas on how to set this up.  This approach is totally new to me.

The intent is to have security so the only visible module is a ddl module that does all the functions of the Original VBA code.

Comment: Am I missing something here. The Office IDE does not allow compiling to a .DLL. Please explain in detail what you have, how you got there and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is this an ExcelDNA question? Please include more details for a better chance of any answer.

Comment: Hello - I used a VBA Compiler by DoneEx to generate the DLL compilation of the VBA code.  Now what I would like to do is replace my VBA code with the DLL and have the excel project run.  I believe I need to put the DLL into a Module, But I believe there needs to be a sub code to call the module.  I need to know how to do this please.

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is in the correct format (COM-DLL), then you can set a reference to it by using the "Tools --> References" menu item in the VBA editor. There, you can either search for the DLL in the filesystem, or if the DLL is registered per `regsvr.exe` (or an .NET assembly with `regasm.exe` tool (see [How can deploy a DLL using RegAsm for COM Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862444))), the DLL should appear in the list.

Comment: How did you creat the DLL? If you created it with C#/VB.NET, then it is an assembly. Else it should be a COM-DLL

Answer (score 0):

This Question has been resolved.  It turns out that DoneEx VBACompiler software does all required and there is no need the embed a DLL file.  So there is no issue anymore on this topic.